# Flutter is not running

Tags: dart, flutter

I tried all the flutter commands but every time it's showing the same error in the command prompt. I have also updated the path but nothing is changing. Even the `flutter doctor` command is also not running at flutter_console.bat

```
  CreateProcessW failed 193

CreateProcessW failed 193
Unhandled exception:
ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

  Command: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
#0      _ProcessImpl._runAndWait (dart:io/runtime/binprocess_patch.dart:488:7)
#1      _runNonInteractiveProcessSync (dart:io/runtime/binprocess_patch.dart:633:18)
#2      Process.runSync (dart:io/runtime/binprocess_patch.dart:66:12)
#3      LocalProcessManager.runSync (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:83:20)
#4      _runWithLoggingSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:324:48)
#5      runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:298:10)
#6      _runGit (package:flutter_tools/src/version.dart:501:10)
#7      new FlutterVersion (package:flutter_tools/src/version.dart:23:16)
#8      runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:64:33)
#9      AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:99:41)
#10     __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection/runtime/libcompact_hash.dart:279:23)
#11     AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:87:20)
#12     AppContext.[] (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:114:32)
#13     FlutterVersion.instance (package:flutter_tools/src/version.dart:170:48)
#14     new Usage (package:flutter_tools/src/usage.dart:26:58)
#15     runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:76:24)
#16     AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:99:41)
#17     __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection/runtime/libcompact_hash.dart:279:23)
#18     AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:87:20)
#19     AppContext.[] (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:114:32)
#20     Usage.instance (package:flutter_tools/src/usage.dart:52:39)
#21     flutterUsage (package:flutter_tools/src/usage.dart:20:33)
#22     _handleToolError (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:113:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:63:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#24     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#25     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#26     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#27     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#28     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#29     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#30     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:42:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#31     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:50:10)
#32     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:52:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#33     main (file:///E:/b/build/slave/Windows_Flutter_Packaging/build/archive/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#34     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:287:32)
#35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

Comment: What does `git --version` print?

Comment: There is a similar issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19359 but also without information how to fix.

Comment: git version 2.15.1.windows.2

Comment: What shell are you using? What directory did you install Flutter into? Does your user name contain a space?

Comment: powershell and path of flutter is "C:\Users\Praneet\Downloads\flutter\bin"

Comment: What do you get if you execute `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE` in the terminal?

Comment: Simple intro to git commands

Comment: Is your PowerShell up-to-date?

Comment: yes PowerShell is updated

Comment: Sorry, don't have time to chat.